# How to replace -MultiViews behaviour in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to catch ALL requests to files in a directory and it's subdirectories and to route them to one single file in a subdirectory. Here is what the htaccess directives look like:

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

  # Excluding one directory
    RewriteRule ^(excludedfolder)($|/).*\.(php)$ - [L]

  # Redirect everything that is html or php to magicscript
    RewriteRule \.(php|html|phps)$ /excludedfolder/magicscript.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /excludedfolder/magicscript.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /excludedfolder/magicscript.php [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . excludedfolder/magicscript.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works on the mostpart of systems.

If i call `someserver.com/testfile.php`, it is properly routed to `magicfile.php`. If i call `someserver.com/testfile`, it also is properly routed to `magicfile.php`. The same for subfolders: If i call `someserver.com/somefolder/testfile.php` or `someserver.com/somefolder/testfile`, it is properly routed to `magicfile.php`.

But on some servers, it is not allowed to set the `Options -MultiViews` which causes the server to completely fail. If I remove the option, it still works, but it doesn't if I don't add the file extension.

How to redirect non existing files to `magicfiles.php` without having to use `Options -MultiViews`? Or how to detect if it is allowed to set the option in php?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't really need to remove `MultiViews` here. What specific problem do you get if you remove `Options -MultiViews` line?

Comment: On a server that does not support `MultiViews`, the server will completely fail on every request because of the htaccess file it doesn't like. If I remove `Options -Multiviews` (and the server has MultiViews enabled by default), it won't route requests correctly if the file extension is missing. Throws a 404 without correctly showing the ErrorDocument I setup.

Comment: Have `MultiViews` enabled can never cause 404.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server do not support `Options -MultiViews` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. But as I wrote, that's exactly the thing I want to circumvent. Either by not using it at all or by detecting if it is usable in php.